# slurm: /usr/local/bin/ different depending on whether logged in or on head node

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to access a program installed on an HPC cluster. When I'm on the head node, it's in /usr/local/bin/. However, when I login using `srun`, /usr/local/bin/ is only the programs I have personally installed for myself locally.

How do I access the general cluster programs in /usr/local/bin? I thought it might be something to do with my .bash_profile, so I reset it to just `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Most cluster use environment modules to manage paths to installed software. Isn't it the case with yours?

Comment: Possibly? I'm new to HPC. Is there a standard way to load the default virtual environment? `source activate default` maybe?

Comment: Try `module avail`. What is the response?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to access a program installed on an HPC cluster.

Are you sure the program is installed cluster wide? From what you write, it seems installed only on the head node, not on the workers. Search the cluster documentation or contact a cluster admin to know if the program should be available on the cluster.

If you installed the program yourself, install it on a volume which is accessible by the workers (like your home, or depending on the cluster any other shared volume you have write access to), not on `/usr/local`.

If the program is indeed in `/usr/local/bin` for the workers but not in your path (that would indicate something odd happened to your `PATH`, probably worth tracking down), you can add it to your path with `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`.